# HTTPS on a Windows 10 IoT web server

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, ssl-certificate, windows-10-iot-core

I want to use a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT Core for a web server in a home automation project. I will have an Arduino pushing data to the Raspberry Pi which will be storing them in a SQLite DB and also hosting a web app where you can log in and monitor the system. I want to encrypt the traffic over HTTPS but is this possible when using Windows 10 IoT Core?

Comment: If you really care about security, an IoT device should never accept incoming connections. *It* should initiate connections to a server to push data or accept commands

Comment: That definitely makes sense and is the closest I've gotten in the matter. As I wrote I want to use the Raspberry as the server (I will get like max 1-2 visitors/day so I really don't need anything beefier than that). That's why it would be nice to be able to run the server on a Raspberry Pi, since I already have one laying around. I will use an Arduino for logging temperature and switch some relays. The Raspberry will just get the values from the Arduino and host a web site for controlling the system.

Comment: I updated the question to include the bit about Arduino etc that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: It's hard to learn new tech if you don't use them ;) I want to learn Windows 10 IoT, that's the main reason.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Let´s Encrypt but only with Windows 10 IoT configuration.

Comment: @Oskar, consider answer your own question here to document your fix.

Comment: @JrBenito: I just meant that I removed the tag for lets-encrypt, not that I have solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across your post looking for the same answer. I see it's been a couple of years since you asked the question, but figured I'll pop what I found in here in case it's useful to you/others: [Running ASP.NET (https) on a Windows 10 IoT device](http://www.devvy.nl/?p=193).

Should be even easier on .net core 3.1 now.